# Power iteration method for finding eigenvector.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

My textbook, wikipedia and the articles I checked are all somewhat ambiguous regarding the convergence to the corresponding eigenvector of the eigenvalue with maximum absolute value.

First, assume the matrix $A \in \mathbb {R}^{n \times n }$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. Also assume that there is just one eigenvalue whose absolute value is the biggest among the other eigenvalues. Denote $|\lambda_1| > |\lambda_2| \geq \cdots \geq |\lambda_n|$ the eigenvalues. It is shown that in this case $\lambda_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. Denote with $e_1,...e_n$ the corresponding eigenvectors. Take an initial estimate $x_0$ such that $x^{(0)} = \alpha_1 e_1 + \dots + \alpha_n e_n$ and $\alpha_1 \neq 0$. Then we can switch the initial estimate and pick $x^{(0)} = \hat e_1 + \hat e_2 + \dots + \hat e_n$ where $\hat e_1 = e_1$ and $\hat e_i$ are such that $A\hat e_i = \lambda_i \hat e_i, i = 2,\dots,n$. Now we have the iteration method $x^{(k+1)} = Ax^{(k)}, k = 0,1,2,...$ and $x^{(k)} = A^{(k)} x^{(0)} = \lambda_1^k (\hat e_1 + \epsilon_k)$ where $\epsilon_k = (\lambda_2/\lambda_1)^k \hat e_2 + \dots + (\lambda_n/\lambda_1)^k \hat e_n$. Now my textbook finds an iterative algorithm that converges to $\lambda_1$. The question remaining is how to find $e_1$. First of all, if $\lambda_1 = 1$ then $x^{(k)} \to e_1$. The algorithm is modified to $$x^{(k+1)} = \dfrac {A x^{(k)}}{\|A x^{(k)}\|}$$ Then $$x^{(k)} = \dfrac {A^k x^{(0)}}{\|A^k x^{(0)}\|}$$ In this case, I observe, that if $\lambda_1 > 0$ then $x^{(k)} \to \dfrac{e_1}{\|e_1\|}$ or generally $x^{(2k)} \to \dfrac{e_1}{\|e_1\|}$ for any $\lambda_1$. But I don't see how $e_1$ could be found from here as we have no information about its norm. Would you please explain this bit? There is some ambiguity in every article I found and in the textbook regarding to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is wrong in finding the unit vector of the eigen-space?

Comment: @LutzLehmann oh I see I assumed the objective was to find $e_1$ specifically

Comment: No, primary is to find the eigenvalues, and secondary any decomposition $A=Q^{-1}BQ$ where $Q$ is often orthogonal and $B$ is (mainly) triangular with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. Then there also applications which require to know the eigenvectors, some or a full basis, often with unit vectors.

Comment: If $e_1$ is an eigenvector, then so is $ce_1$, for all nonzero scalars $c$.